# How to filter and sort the Dictionary object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have below data in my dictionary object.

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, Component>> lstCountry = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Component>>();

//Sample data in above dictionary object

ASIA, Component object(India)
ASIA, Component object(China)
ASIA, Component object(Sri Lanka)
ASIA, Component object(Bangladesh)
..
..
..
EUROPE, Component object(United Kingdom)
EUROPE, Component object(Germany)
EUROPE, Component object(France)
..
..
```

Now I want to add these values in to another master countries dictionary which will have sample data below:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Component>> dicCountries = new Dictionary<string, List<Component>>();

//ASIA, List<Component> Object of all the ASIA countries
//AFRICA, List<Component> Object of all the AFRICA countries
//EUROPE, List<Component> Object of all the EUROPE countries
...
```

...

Please suggest whether this possible using LINQ or we can achieve with simple C# coding.

Comment: Your sample data does not make sense. How can you have duplicate keys in a dictionary?

Comment: @Leppie, any other suggestions?

Comment: Not unless you edit your question to be not nonsensical.

Comment: @leppie is right.  Are you sure you don't mean `Dictionary<String, List<Component>>` in the first place?

Comment: Agree, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @leppie is right! YOU CANT ADD FEW values with a same key to one dictionary!

Comment: You should use List<KeyValuePair<String, Component>>!

Comment: or List<Tuple<String, Component>>

Comment: @Maris, let take List<KeyValuePair<String, Component>>, please suggest what other thing can be done after ward.

Comment: @Xaruth bad idea to use Tuple in this context!

Comment: @Maris **IMO** Tuple is more scalable and seems to be faster http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple-keyvaluepair

Comment: @Xaruth, pls look once more to the link you referenced. There is using simple types! The performance boost will be down when we will use entity Component in the tuple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the input is not a dictionary(makes no sense) but a `List<KeyValuePair<String, Component>>`, this works:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Component>> dicCountries = lstCountry
        .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key) // added OrderBy because of your title although it's not clear
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToList());
```

If you also want to order the components you have to add the `OrderBy` before the `ToList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, Component>> dataNotGrouped;
var grouped = dataNotGrouped.GroupBy(e=>e.Key);
```

Done.

Then you can convert it to `Dictionary<String, List<Component>>` or to `List<KeyValuePair<String, Component>>` or whateva you want! Your list is getting grouped by the Key!